# Custom ListAdapter is not Updating

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I am working on a project where I am displaying a list of Car owners. Upon accessing the application, an empty list is displayed. The user search for an owner, and we display all available owners that matche the search criteria. 
The issue that I ran into is that the owner list is updated, but it also show "No record to be displayed" which is what an empty list is supposed to show. What I am missing here?
Here are the relevant classes

```
   public class OwnerDetail extends ListFragment {
    ListView mListView;
   ArrayList<Owner> listItem = new ArrayList<Owner>();
   public OwnerAdapter ownerAdapter;
   private String[] searchParameter = null;

   public void SearchParameters(String[] parameters)
   {
       searchParameter = parameters;
   }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customize_layout,container, false);
        mListView = (ListView) v1.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        return v1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ownerAdapter = new OwnerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.owner_detail, listItem);
        if(!(searchParameter == null))
        {
            ownerAdapter.clear();
            ownerAdapter.addAll(listItem);
            new OnwerAsyncTask().execute();
            ownerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mListView.setAdapter(ownerAdapter);
        ownerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class OnwerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Owner>> {
        @Override
        protected List<Owner> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try
            {
                Owner items = new Owner();
                items.setFirstName("John");
                items.setLastName("Smith");
                items.setCarId("1");
                listItem.add(items);

                Owner item1 = new Owner();
                item1.setFirstName("Samantha");
                item1.setLastName("Right");
                item1.setCarId("2");
                listItem.add(item1);

                Owner item2 = new Owner();
                item2.setFirstName("Regie");
                item2.setLastName("Miller");
                item2.setCarId("3");
                listItem.add(item2);

                Owner item3 = new Owner();
                item3.setFirstName("Mark");
                item3.setLastName("Adam");
                item3.setCarId("4");
                listItem.add(item3);


            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.toString();
            }
            return listItem;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            listItem.clear();
            ownerAdapter.clear();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Owner> result) {
            /*OwnerDetail  fragment = (OwnerDetail) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fOwnerDetail);
            fragment.SetAdapter(result);*/
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(listItem.size() > 0)
            {
                ownerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}    



 public class OwnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Owner> {

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private Owner data[] = null;

    public OwnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,Owner[] data) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        OwnerHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new OwnerHolder();
            holder.tvFName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);
            holder.tvLName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvLastName);
            holder.tvCId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvCarID);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else
        {
            holder = (OwnerHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Owner item = data[position];
        holder.tvFName.setText(item.getFirstName());
        holder.tvLName.setText(item.getLastName());
        holder.tvCId.setText(item.getCarId());
        return row;
    }

    static class OwnerHolder
    {
      TextView tvFName;
      TextView tvLName;
      TextView tvCId;
    }
}
```

Edit on 08/06/2013 
I updated the OwnerDetail class and added the asyncktask as a private inner class. It displayed the list, but it showed the "No Record to be displayed" too.

owner_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFirstName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLastName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCarID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="TextView" />


</LinearLayout>


// customize_layout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

     <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="No record to be displayed." 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding data to adapter in `onPostExecute`:

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Owner> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ownerAdapter.clear();
            ownerAdapter.addAll(result);
            ownerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.i("TESTING","Added " + result.size() + " items to adapter");
    }
```

Also, I see you are using custom list layout, make sure empty TextView has id `@android/id/empty` and visibility set to `gone`.

Comment: I change it to add the adapter in onPostExecute and set the textview visibility to gone, it still did not clear the "No record to be display."

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Owner> result) {
listItem = (ArrayList<Owner>) result;
super.onPostExecute(result);
if(listItem.size() > 0)
{
ownerAdapter.clear()
ownerAdapter.addAll(listItem);
ownerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}}

Comment: @Gagouche Place a log (see updated code answer) and see if this is show in logcat output when you run. If not, the task id not finishing at all.

Comment: I edit the original story to add the customize xml files. it shows 4 items added to the Adapter. I can see the 4 items in the list. However, it also show "No Record to be display" which the default text to show for empty list.

Comment: @Gagouche try the layout given here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: this is very interesting. I replaced it with the xml layout in the sample, and it worked as expected with the red background. Then, I removed the background color, and I can see the "no data" in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the Adapter because when you create the Fragment `owner` will be `null` and so the fragment is initialized with the empty row.

Modify your `SetAdapter(Owner[] o)` as follows:

```
public void SetAdapter(Owner[] o) {
    owner = o;
    ownerAdapter.clear();
    ownerAdapter.addAll(o);
    ownerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```